# How to add event to iCal / Outlook / gmail from webpage?

Tags: coldfusion, outlook, gmail, icalendar

include a link to download an .ics / .iCal file?  attach .ics file through email?

How to construct the file?  Where to find the spec?

What're the benefits of rendering the data in hCalendar on the page?  So search engine can index it somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be plenty of hits for the first part of your question on Google.  Also try CFLIB.org search and you can see how the function creates the text string
http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=iCal+and+ColdFusion

To download, write out the string to the browser using CFCONTENT.  To attach to an email, write out the string to a temporary file and you can use CFMAILPARAM to attach it.  Those are a couple of ways.

Comment: Sorry Henry was on my phone when answered the question, here is the spec for iCal, very dry read :)

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt

Also there is a MIME type to use if you use with CFCONTENT too 'text/calendar'.

Comment: here is also a way to send the iCal as an attachment on an email without creating the temporary file  http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2007/10/26/Using-CFMAIL-to-send-attachments-stored-in-memory